# Install and setup BlueOcean for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I want to install Blue Ocean for Jenkins. Can anyone tell me the steps to do this.

Answer (score 8):

[Enable the experimental update centre](https://jenkins.io/blog/2013/09/23/experimental-plugins-update-center/) by changing the url under manage plugins > advanced > update site to

```
https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/experimental/update-center.json
```

Check for updates by clicking “check now”. Enable the [(Alpha) BlueOcean plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blue+Ocean+Plugin).

Answer (score 2):

```
docker run -p 8888:8080 jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker compose for Jenkins blueocean with persistent storage on host directory "/var/lib/jenkins" -

```
version: "3"

services:
  jenkinsblue:
    image: jenkinsci/blueocean
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
```

Access URL - http://[SERVER-IP]:8080

Comment: We can add nginx as a reverse proxy as well & integrate it in the compose file.